# How to go totally fullscreen in a st terminal on a PocketC.H.I.P.?

Tags: terminal, fullscreen, terminal-emulator, ntc-pocketchip, st-terminal

I use the `st` terminal emulator on a PocketCHIP. Unfortunately, I have grey borders on the right and the bottom of the screen. It looks like the terminal is not full screen.

How can I maximize the `st` window on PocketCHIP?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only solution I was able to come up with is to modify the configuration header of st and change `static int borderpx` from default `2` to `0`.

It gets rid of the border on the right. It doesn't hide the border on the bottom however.

In fact, it might not be possible in the vanilla version of `st` because its maximal window width and height is determined by the number of row and columns of characters it is physically possible to fit on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You need to patch st

Download diff patch file here: https://st.suckless.org/patches/anysize/

Apply it with the following:

```
# cd program-directory
# git apply path/to/patch.diff
```